# ActionBar won't change colour when trying to change colour in dark mode in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, colors, themes

I am trying to change the colour of my actionbar in my app in android studio. I have added a night\colors.xml file to my values directory in order to change the colour in my night\themes.xml file and have tried adding in a new colour instead of the colour of my actionbar which is black. I have replaced any black colour with a different colour yet the actionbar doesn't change, only certain text changes thats it, how do I fix this problem?

Here is the code to my night\themes.xml:

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here is the code to my nights\colors.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#239090</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#239090</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#239090</color>
    <color name="grey">#242B2E</color>
</resources>
```

(I changed the colours back to black by the way in this code)

Here is also the code in my themes.xml if it helps with anything:

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this in two in your `values\themes.xml`,

```
<item name="colorSurface">@color/blue_normal</item>
<item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
```

Make sure that `colorSurface` is same as `colorPrimary` and `colorOnSurface` is same as `colorOnPrimary`

Reason for this is that Light theme is set default to `Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Primary` and the Dark theme default to `Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Surface`.

Because of this in dark mode `Primary colors` are not preferred but `Surface colors`, so you have to use `Surface color`.

Comment: why do I need to add these and can't just change the primary colours?

Comment: I have edited the answer check again, consider upvotiing if it helps.